# Tizen web app on wearable device to operate on desktop application

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app, samsung-galaxy-gear, cross-device

I am wondering if Tizen platform supports to develop a web app for wearable devices(Samsung galaxy) that can operate on desktop application(example selection/navigation of menus in desktop application through smartwatch features like touch,button,bevel) using Bluetooth technology ?? i am very new to tizen platform and any inputs/abstract on how to build this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Tizen platform already supports the web app for the wearable device.
You can refer the document for web application of wearable (https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application).
And you can use the bluetooth API(https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/connectivity-and-wireless/bluetooth).